# CSV file to an ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, string, csv, arraylist

I have imported my file and am now looking to add the csv file into an array. When I create a new arraylist and try to read the imported file into the array (file named "b") I am receiving an error that says b cannot be resolved to a variable. Is there a simpler way to import a csv file and have the file put into an array?

```
public static void main (String[] args) {

        //import csv file
        FileReader myFileReader = null;{
        try {
            myFileReader = new FileReader("src/NFLPlayers.csv");
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Error opening file: " + ex.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        BufferedReader b = null; 
        b = new BufferedReader(myFileReader);
//Loop through all the records in the file and print them on the console
        while (true){ 
            String myLine; 
            try {
                myLine = b.readLine();
                //check for null returned from readLine() and exit loop if so. 
                if (myLine ==null){break;} 
                System.out.println(myLine); 
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                 //it is time to exit the while loop
                break;}
            }
        }

            }
```

Here is where I am trying to take the csv file and put into the array:

```
public ArrayList<NFLPlayer> ReadFromDataFile (String fileName){
        ArrayList<NFLPlayer> NFLPlayerList = new ArrayList <NFLPlayer>(); 
        //read from the file. use String.Split() to break up the comma-separated values
        NFLPlayerList.add(new NFLPlayer (b));
         //Loop through all the records in the file and print them on the console   
        return NFLPlayerList; 
    }


}
```

Comment: Your problem is not related to CSV parsing, but to elementary principles of programming. A local variable of one method cannot be referenced from another method.

Comment: To add to Marko's comment, `b` would not even be the correct variable if it was in scope. You don't store your `BufferedReader` in the list, you store `myLine`, the line you read with `b`

Comment: @JGrice is there a way to store the csv file directly into the array?

Comment: @NewbieGirl The process you posted is the common method to convert csv to array, but that is not the problem with your code. You are trying to access variables in methods where that variable is out of scope.

Comment: I would suggest searching for your exact post title on this site. There are a large number of solutions for this, as converting csv to lists is a common question.

Comment: @JGrice I understand so how could I create a new variable that would be assigned to that csv file that is being called in the first method?

Comment: @NewbieGirl Look at your comments in your `ReadFromDataFile` method. Those comments describe the steps you are implementing in your main method. All the code you posted should be moved into your `ReadFromDataFile` method and you simply iterate over your csv, line by line, and call the arrayList.add() method for each line. Breakdown of steps: open file (init bufferedReader); init arrayList;   for each line in csv, readLine from file into variable; add variable to list

Comment: @JGrice I have myLine=b.readLine(); to read the line of the file. How do I assign each line that is being read into a variable?

Comment: @NewbieGirl `myLine=b.readLine()` does what you are describing. myLine is the variable containing the line from the file, `b` is the `BufferedReader` you use to read from the file, and `readLine()` is the method that gets a line from the file. You just keep calling that code every time you want a new line.

Comment: @JGrice so for each line could I do myLine1=b.readLine(), myLine2=b.readLine()? Then when I want to add to the array do I do NFLPlayerList.add (myLine1); and so on?

Comment: @NewbieGirl Just use the same `myLine` variable every time. The `readLine()` method will replace `myLine`'s value. I would suggest reviewing your understanding of variables and working with them; this is a core concept of programming.

Comment: @JGrice Thank you for your help! Im certainly still learning!!